# gdal_rasterize a large geopackage

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-rasterize

Trying to run this command with gdal_rasterize:

gdal_rasterize --config CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE NO -co "PREDICTOR=2" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -of GTiff -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -ot Byte -l my_layer -a field_to_burn -tr 0.000277777781132076 0.000277777781132076 -a_nodata 255 "c:/tmp/input.gpkg" "c:/tmp/output.tif"

The input geopackage is about 80GB (global dataset at fairly high resolution).

I get these errors and it crashes:

ERROR 1: In GetNextRawFeature(): sqlite3_step() : disk I/O error

ERROR 2: D:\src\osgeo4w\zsrc\gdal\gdal-3.6.3\alg\gdalrasterize.cpp, 1147: cannot allocate vector 2147024896 bytes

Any ideas?

Comment: With those parameters you are trying to create a raster with 1296000x648000 pixels. That is rather big, around 840 GB as uncompressed and maybe 80 GB with LZW compression if I compute right. Anyway, that is not the problem but by the error message the gdalrasterize function is not prepared to deal with so big vector data. I guess it hits a limit of 2 gigabytes that is reserved in the code for some variable. Split your task into smaller bits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it's a big raster, and I did expect it to be around 80GB output at the end. I guess I could rasterize it in 4 sections of the world, and then stitch them together afterwards?

Comment: Yes, the resulting rasters are georeferenced and with lossless compression so stitching them together should make no problem at all. Iterate with `-te <xmin> <ymin> <xmax> <ymax>` for finding the limits.

Comment: Would you recommend making a VRT from the resulting rasters and then running gdal_translate on the VRT to realise the rasters to one file?

Comment: I think that's what I would do. Or I might just use the VRT but it depends on the use case.